# cv2.imshow() not responding after showing few images to a window one by one when images are coming from front end

Tags: python, opencv, flask, python-imaging-library

From front end in every second a request comes along with a image of string. I have tested that numpy array of images is created by calling write_image() every time the request are coming from the front end. I am able to show every image for a request separately using show() method of pillow module. Everything is fine until using cv2. When I use cv2.imshow() method to show image into a window like video, then the imshow method can only show 6 images one by one to that window created by cv2.namedWindow('stream', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL).

I want to show every image to a window like video is playing.

**app.py**

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request
import cv2
from PIL import Image


app = Flask(__name__)


def write_image(image):
    data = base64.b64decode(image)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
    np_array = np.array(img)
    cv2.namedWindow('stream', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('stream', np_array)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


@app.route('/frame/upload/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_image():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.form['images']  # base64
        write_image(file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=True)
```

[Every image should be displayed to the window against every request like video is playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z02OQ.png)

Comment: Provide OS and hardware details...? Also: did you try getting stream from file or device? Did you use the CV2 example?

Comment: Hello DeDenker, OS is ubuntu 16.04 Lts, Memory: 11.6 GB, Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4 , Graphics Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) , OS type: 64-bit, Disk: 235.2 GB

Comment: Ah, next time mention you are using Flask to render the image on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Using the print function might cause buffer problem, not sure what goes wrong.
Take a look at the Flask response function.
The Flask example on video streaming is like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame() #r_server.get(get)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Credits: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask

Comment: Thanks for your response. Though my scenario is completely different.

Comment: Then try the ** return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),                     mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame') ** as your usage of PRINT might be the issue.